# Drupal theme files outside of theme folder

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-theming, drupal-themes

Is there a place where I can place override theme files other than a theme's folder? For example, if I wanted to override the appearance of a view's row in the same style for more than one theme without having to use more than one file.

If there isn't a generic way to do this (for any theme file), is there a way to do it for a view's theme files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your module, you can use hook_theme to declare a theme function or template for your view's row. This way, your single template will be used by all your themes without any special code in them. See the *Theming your views in your module* section in the [Views's API](http://views-help.doc.logrus.com/help/views/api-default-views) Advanced Help page.

Answer (score 1):

You could include an `include_once` type statement in your tpl.php file and just import the code from where ever. This way you have any number of files that refer to one.

It is not recommended though since if you move your theme folder or rename anything this can be harder. Also if you put your theme in another site you need to keep track of all of these off-theme hacks.

Answer (score 0):

I think views seeks tpls inside of the theme folder. It's be nice to have something like that though.